# Bootstrap: How to place button next to input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't work out (conforming to "proper bootstrap") how to get a button to sit next to an input-group within a div.

They need to be center aligned.

This is what I want it to look like...

[image: Good]

This is what is happening...

[image: Bad]

Here is my current code.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created this js fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/ptwbn2av/

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could also try the [pull-left](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) class.

> The classes .pull-left and .pull-right also exist and were previously
>   used as part of the media component, but are deprecated for that use
>   as of v3.3.0. They are approximately equivalent to .media-left and
>   .media-right, except that .media-right should be placed after the
>   .media-body in the html.

The html:

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use:

```
style="margin-right:5px"
```

to add some spacing after the div, and then the new mark-up would be as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right:5px">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest yet. Thanks!

Comment: no problem:] looks like it also needs some `margin-right` there, though.

Comment: Exactly. Close but not quite :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. let me also check if it's possible with using a bootstrap class instead of inline styling.

Comment: I really don't want to hardcode styling. This is what I am trying to get away from by using bootstrap

Comment: i understand, let me check that. be back after lunch:]

Comment: I have created a class of input-group-left-sibling and set the margin to 5px. Combined with a pull-left, this is a good solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

With your current code, you can use the flexbox.

A powerful CSS layout module that gives us an efficient and simple way to lay out and align things.

```
<div class="flex">
   <div>
     <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

.flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

This is the screenshot of the result: [image]

You can learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

`div`s are *block elements*, which means that they align vertically. For example,

```
<div>
    Hello World!
</div>
<div>
    Goodbye World!
</div>
```

would result in:

```
Hello World!

Goodbye World!
```

So, in order to make the elements flow horizontally, you have to make the `div` *inline* because inline elements can flow horizontally, such as text and `<span>`.

You can add a rule to your css:

```
#delete-button {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And of course, you should add an id attribute to the button.

If the above doesn't work, you should consider putting all the elements in one `div` because `<button>`, `<input>`, and `<span>` are all inline elements.

Comment: This is correct... but this isn't "pure" bootstrap. I would expect there would be a way simply using predefined classes.

Comment: This explanation is great, i always had issues when trying to align things horizontally. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here one solution to the problem.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary border-left-0 border" type="button">
            Delete
        </button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control py-2" value="1" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the output at this link: [codeply.com/p/xijLBe2vff](https://codeply.com/p/xijLBe2vff).

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/p/xijLBe2vff   u can check output from this link

Answer (score 1):

Just add the grid classes. Try this

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xbu9qtje/

Comment: This will mess up the center alignment. BTW... your fiddle isn't right

Comment: This would mess up the center alignment as the button sizes etc are defined "responsively"

Answer (score 0):

Try the `form-inline` class in the root div, it will default to "inline" putting your fields one next to the other:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
      <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just put

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "input-group-addon", @style = "width:50px;text-align:center;" } })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">Update</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I add col classes, the center alignment will be wrong.